# Autofac - Using Multiple Implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, autofac

With `Autofac`, I am registering 2 implementations with a type. And need to swap the implementations on demand. But it is always taking one implementation.

```
public class DataAccesss
{
    public IDatabaseHelper { get; set; }
}
```

Autofac

```
builder.RegisterType<DatabaseHelper>()
       .Named<IDatabaseHelper>("Sql")
       .WithParameter(new TypedParameter(IDatabaseHelper), new DatabaseHelper(new SqlFactory))
       .PropertiesAutowired();

builder.RegisterType<DatabaseHelper>()
       .Named<IDatabaseHelper>("Oledb")
       .WithParameter(new TypedParameter(IDatabaseHelper), new DatabaseHelper(new OleDbFactory))
       .PropertiesAutowired();
```

And in controller, need to have something like this

```
1st - need to access `IDatabaseHelper` with `OleDb`
2nd - need to access  `IDatabaseHelper` with `Sql`
```

But my issue is `IDatabaseHelper` is either `null` or it is always taking `OleDb` and not `Sql`.

Comment: What do you mean by *On demand* ? different implementation for different service ?

Comment: with same service I need to access both `OleDbClient` and `SqlClient`

Comment: IF you write as, it will always taking OleDb, 1 interface only get SqlFactory OR OleDbFactory

Comment: Yes obviously, but I have a scenario to use one after the other. `OleDbFactory` at 1st and `SqlFactory` at 2nd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you resolve a single component *Autofac* will return the latest registered component that match the operation.

If you need to access both service in your implementation you can have a dependency on `IEnumerable<IDatabaseHelper>` which will resolve all `IDatabaseHelper` registered service.

Another solution would be to rely on `IIndex<TKey, TValue>` and named registration

```
public class XController 
{
    public XController(IIndex<String, IDatabaseHelper> databaseHelpers) 
    {
        this._databaseHelpers = databaseHelpers; 
    }

    private readonly IIndex<String, IDatabaseHelper> _databaseHelpers;

    public void Do()
    {
        IDatabaseHelper oledb = this._databaseHelpers["Oledb"];
    }
}
```

and your registration will be like :

```
builder.Register(c => new DatabaseHelper(new SqlFactory()))
       .Named<IDatabaseHelper>("Sql")
       .PropertiesAutowired();

builder.Register(c => new DatabaseHelper(new OleDbFactory()))
       .Named<IDatabaseHelper>("Oledb")
       .PropertiesAutowired();
```

See [Named and Keyed service](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html) from *Autofac* documentation for more information